# How to align text in a button in flutter?

Tags: button, text, dart, flutter, alignment

I just want to do the most simplest of things: I just want to have a button with the text aligned to the right. For some reason I can't figure this out.

I tried textAlign: TextAlign.right but it's still in the centre. I tried making a row inside the button with mainAxisAlignment.end but nope, still in center. for some reason it works if I use main axis alignment.end on a column instead of a row (puts it at bottom instead of right)

This is what I have so far:

```
FlatButton(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            "M",
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            style: TextStyle(
            color: mColor, fontSize: 10.0),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it in an inkwell

```
InkWell(
    onTap: doSomething,
    child: SizedBox(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            child: Text(
                'hello',
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Also, I figured out you can use stack to overlay a button on top of a text widget but this is neater.

Answer (score 48):

You should put your 'Text' in 'Align' to align your text left, right, top, bottom etc. As-

```
    FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  /*...*/
                },
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "Flat",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center
                  ),
                ))
```

Comment: It didn't work.

`FlatButton(
     color: Colors.black,
     child: Align(
     alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Text(
     "M",
      style: TextStyle(
       color: mColor, fontSize: 10.0),
      ),
       ),
`
That code produces [this.](https://imgur.com/a/DvpTKYV)
But changing to Alignment.topCentre produces [this.](https://imgur.com/VplWQv7)

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 13):

It works for me

```
  ButtonTheme(
    child: FlatButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          "Button text",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: ThemeColors.primaryDark,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            fontSize: ThemeSizes.normalFont,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () => _doSomething(),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: FlatButton and ButtonTheme are not used anymore, use the new TextButton and TextButtonTheme instead. See breaking changes here: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Comment: Thanks , doing this    child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(  worked for me

Answer (score 7):

For the new Buttons and Button Themes:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Cancel'),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, // <-- had to set alignment
    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
      EdgeInsets.zero, // <-- had to set padding to zero
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

The following examples use the [new Buttons and Button Themes](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons) recommended in the Flutter doc. There are two simple and elegant approaches to this problem

**First approach:** use a top-level `TextButtonTheme` that will pass the same styles down to all `TextButton` descendant widgets

```dart
Container(
  width: double.maxFinite,
  child: TextButtonTheme(
    data: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.black87,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
          label: Text('Manage your account'),
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
          label: Text('Favorites'),
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.reviews_outlined),
          label: Text('Reviews'),
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
          label: Text('Sign out'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Second approach:** individually style each separate button (each one has different styles) instead of styling all of them at once using the same styles as done above

```dart
TextButton.icon(style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.blue))
TextButton.icon(style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green))
```

[More about the styleFrom() method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/styleFrom.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the padding values in the FlatButton widget worked very well.

See example below...

```
 FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
           /*...*/
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, bottom: 1.0, top: 1.0),
        child: Text(
          'Getting Started',
          style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                        fontSize: 12.0
          ), //TextStyle
         ), //Text
        ), //FlatButton
```

Comment: Emm, thats terrible idea :) Sorry. If text changes and button has fixed width or full screen width you'll run into big problems and you wont even know it :) using padding will only work if button does not have set width of any kind

Answer (score 2):

Using 'ButtonStyle' worked for the new TextButton(not for the old FlatButton).

```
TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft),
    child: Text(
        'Push!',
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    ),
    onPressed:() {
        // Do something.
    },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using TextButton, but this should work for all of the new button widgets: ElevatedButton, OutlinedButton, TextButton

```
// ...your widget hierarchy...
TextButton(
  onPressed: () => print('Logic goes here'),
  child: Text('Button Alignment Example'),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  ),
),
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not believe but sometimes **the little height imperfections are due to the text's height**. In this example, I'm using a `TextButton` (but it actually works for the other cases too).

```
   TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("Do this");
          },
          child: Text(
            "Title",
            style: TextStyle(
              height: 1, //I set this to one.
              color: Color(0xff191919),
              letterSpacing: 0,
            ),
          ),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            primary: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put in your TextButton's style property:

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0)),
```

Comment: Remember you can also cut off padding. Try it out, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but here is what I am doing in case it helps anyone.

```
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textButtonTheme
                        .style!
                        .copyWith(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft),
```

since it matches the styleFrom from here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a Container and use the align attribute:

```
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Your text')),
```

Answer (score 0):

ElevatedButton Example

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.search,
    color: Colors.grey.shade600,
  ),
  label: Text(
    'ElevatedButton',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ButtonStyle(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    backgroundColor:
        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade300),
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    )),
  ),
),
```

Basic

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.search,
  ),
  label: Text(
    'Search',
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ButtonStyle(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using Elevated Button. If you didn't add other properties like Colum or Row, etc., use **alignment** in **.StyleFrom**.

```
ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {}, // Your OnPress Sequence
                                      child: Text( "Hello"),
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        minimumSize: const Size(360, 70), // Button Minimum Width
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)), // For Rounded Corner
                                        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey), // Border Color
                                        elevation: 0, // Elevation
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), // Text Padding
                                        primary: Colors.white, // Primary Button Color
                                        onPrimary: Colors.black, // Text Color if didn't Specify with text
                                        alignment:Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      ),
                                    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use row as children, here the implementation in flutter 2 with TextButton

```
TextButton(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Text('Text', style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black54
      )),
    ],
  ),
  onPressed: _action,
)
```